# Django pass parameter to web page via ListView class

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^index',
    ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:4], template_name="personal/index.html")),
]
```

and a template file header.html where I have next lines

```
< header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('{% static background_image %}')">
. . .
</header>
```

As you see I'm trying to set a background image to header, which path is held in background_image variable, I want to know how can I pass this parameter

Is there any way to do it, or am I doing it completely wrong?

Comment: Do you want to pass the parameter value from your server ?

Comment: ListView will give you list of objects.How are you searching for variable background_image ?

Comment: Where is that variable supposed to be coming from?

Comment: before I start to use ListView, i used      render(request, 'personal/index.html', {'background_image': 'personal/img/home-bg.jpg'})

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add extra variables to the context of a Django CBV by subclassing the view and overriding [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data):

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:4]
    template_name = "personal/index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['background_image'] = 'personal/img/home-bg.jpg'
        return context
```

Then update your url pattern to use your new view:

```
url(r'^index', PostListView.as_view())
```

Comment: thanks that helped me, btw, you forgot "return context" statement

Comment: Thanks, I've added the return statement.